# CloudStorageTools::serve() audio not playing on iOS

Tags: ios, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, html5-audio

I'm using `GoogleCloudStorage::serve()` to serve `.mp3` files via a website on `Google App Engine` with an `HTML5` `audio` tag. Everything was working fine, but after an update for `iOS`, these devices were unable to play the audio in any browser.

I'm not sure why the code stopped working. Everything else still works fine on Android and Windows in all browsers.

It doesn't relay on Javascript or auto play at all. It's just a simple audio tag with the source being provided by `GoogleCloudStorage::serve()`, which works everywhere except recently on iOS.

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is a shot in the dark because I don't know anything about serving audio files on iOS, but in case it helps...

About the same time you posted this question, a friend asked me to help him with his website.  The website previously played audio, but around the time of your question, the audio stopped working on Safari on OS X.

The existing audio player that was being used was Flash based.  I switched his website to playing audio using HTML5 and then it worked fine.

So you may want to check if you are playing audio in iOS with a Flash player and change it to HTML5 if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the input, but it's already using HTML5. When I hit play nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

Do you rely on **autoplay**? iOS disables autoplay, you really **have to** 
let the user touch a button, or something.

Quote from [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may
>   be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and
>   autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it.
>   This means the JavaScript `play()` and `load()` methods are also inactive
>   until the user initiates playback, unless the `play()` or `load()` method
>   is triggered by user action. In other words, a user-initiated Play
>   button works, but an `onLoad="play()"` event does not.
>
> This plays the movie: `<input type="button" value="Play"
>   onclick="document.myMovie.play()">`
>
> This does **nothing on iOS**: `<body onload="document.myMovie.play()">`

Comment: No. It's just a basic HTML audio tag. Hitting play does nothing. Works everywhere else except iOS.